# $CD+C+D=0$, show that $CD=DC$

Tags: matrix-equations

So say we have two ($n \times n$)-matrices $C$ and $D$ and also that $CD+C+D=0$

Prove that $CD=DC$.

I'm kind of curious about this one and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Add $I$ to both sides of the original equation, and factor the left-hand side to get
$$ (C+I)(D+I)=I $$
Now remember that inverses are always two-sided.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that any matrix here but $I$ has an inverse?

Comment: $(C+I)(D+I)=CD+CI+ID+I=(CD+C+D)+I=0+I$. And as Henning says in real matrices having one sided inverse implies two sided inverse. So the point is $C+I$ and $D+I$ are inverses for themselves.

Comment: ah damn, stupid me.

Comment: Is it possible that then both C and D are zero-matrices?

Comment: @Matrix1: Sure. $C=D=0$ satisfies both your assumption and the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot gentlemen for your guick feedback! I think I now get the idea behind all of it.